# ¿Se puede llamar a un controller desde un archivo .cshtml sin Razor, con AJAX?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

**Hola, buenos dias.**

Estoy iniciando un proyecto nuevo en Visual studio, el cual desconozco bastante. La propuesta del proyecto ha sido crear un proyecto con sus controllers, vistas, modelos, etc... Pero sin usar Razor, tengo que llamar al controller, usando solamente AJAX., ni ASP ni nada, fichero cshtml.

¿Hay alguna manera de llamar al controller usando solamente AJAX?

Comment: Puedes usar javascript directamente o alguna libreria jquery por ejemplo, y no tiene que ser cshtml puedes usar html.

Answer (score 0):

Realiza la llamada `Ajax`con JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'NombreControlador/NombreAccion',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
       //Codigo
    },
    error: function (data) {
       //Codigo
    }
});
```